# How to I use LINQ to get last date only

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
public class ModelData
{
    public string name;
    public DateTime DT;
    public int real;
    public int trade;
    public int position;
    public int dayPnl;
    public double ATR;
    public double C2C;
    public double C;
}

List<ModelData> modelData;

var priorDateRealTrades = modelData
        .Where(x => x.DT.Date <= aDate.Date)
        .OrderBy(x => x.DT.Date)
        .ToArray();
```

I only really want where to select 1 element for each "name".

My query gives me all elements with a prior date and then orders them.

How can I just return one element (the most recent prior date) for each "name"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GroupBy() and FirstOrDefault()

```
var priorDateRealTrades = modelData
  .GroupBy(d => d.Name)
  .Select(gd => gd.Where(x => x.DT.Date <= aDate.Date)
    .OrderBy(x => x.DT.Date)
    .First())
  .ToList()
```

This will group by the name, and then select the first one orderd/where'd per group.  This will throw an exception if no records match the date where/criteria.  This may be a requirement...

OR

```
var priorDateRealTrades = modelData
  .GroupBy(d => d.Name)
  .Select(gd => gd.Where(x => x.DT.Date <= aDate.Date)
    .OrderBy(x => x.DT.Date)
    .FirstOrDefault())
  .Where(d => d != null)
  .ToList()
```

This will do the same as the previous, but will also filter out results that have no dates matching (they will be null) and throw no exception.

Comment: why don't you use FirstOrDefault() instead of First() ? this can cause exception on Where clause

Comment: Actually, you and Jake came to similar solutions. I am choosing yours as it is slightly closer to mine. However, Jake spotted the need for Descending in OrderBy. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like:

```
var query = modelData
    .Where(x => x.DT.Date <= aDate.Date)
    .GroupBy(r => r.name)
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Name = grp.Key,
        LastDate = grp.OrderBy(t => t.DT.Date).FirstOrDefault()
    });
```

What it does is:

- Apply filter for `Date`
- Group filtered values based on Name
- Select `Name` and only *single* `Date` after ordering.

If you are only interested in getting `Date` values, then your query should be:

```
var query = modelData
    .Where(x => x.DT.Date <= aDate.Date)
    .GroupBy(r => r.name)
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(t => t.DT.Date).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
var priorDateRealTrades = modelData.Where(t => t.DT <= aDate.Date && t.DT <= DateTime.Now).OrderByDescending(t => t.DT).FirstOrDefault();
```

Edit:

Sorry, I didn't realize that your names may be duplicated.

```
var priorDateRealTrades = modelData
.GroupBy(t => t.name)
.Select(t => t.Where(t2 => t2.DT <= aDate.Date && t2.DT <= DateTime.Now).OrderByDescending(t3 => t3.DT)
.FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use [`IEnumerable.Distinct()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) and create a class that implements 
[`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.100).aspx).

It could be something like this:

```
public class ModelData
{
    public string name;
    public DateTime DT;
    public int real;
    public int trade;
    public int position;
    public int dayPnl;
    public double ATR;
    public double C2C;
    public double C;
}

private class ModelDataNameComparator : IEqualityComparer<ModelData>
{
    public bool Equals(ModelData x, ModelData y)
    {
        return x.name.Equals(x.name.ID);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ModelData obj)
    {
        return obj.name.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {        
        List<ModelData> modelData = ModelRepository.GetAllModelDataFromMagicPlace();

        var priorDateRealTrades = modelData.OrderByDescending(d => d.DT)
                                           .Distinct(new ModelDataNameComparator())
                                           .ToList();
        foreach(ModelData md in priorDateREalTrades)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("name: {0}, Date: {1}", md.name, md.DT);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you and if do, plese mark it as answer :)